# next content on click angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api

how to display the following content on click ?

I have a content list that I display until 20 then click I would like to display the rest

I created the nextMovieList method for that

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService, Movie } from './shared/services/movies.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app-entretien';
  moviesList: Movie[];
  moviesSelected: Movie[];

  currentPage: number = 0;

  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moviesService.getList(1, 20).subscribe(data => {
      this.moviesList = data.content;
      console.log(this.moviesList);
    });
  }

  nextMoviesList() {
    if (this.currentPage > this.moviesList.length) {
      this.currentPage++
    }
  }
}
```

**movies.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


export interface Movie {
  attributes: {
    actors: string; // acteurs
    description: string; // synopsis
    director: string; // réalisateur
    duration: string; // durée en minute
    title: string; // titre
    year: string; // année de sortie
  };
  thumbnails: { // jaquettes
    large: string;
    medium: string;
    small: string;
    tiny: string;
    xlarge: string;
  };
}

export interface ApiReturn<T> {
  code: number;
  content: T[];
  count: number;
  description: string;
  details: string;
  limit: number;
  page: number;
  sort: string;
}

export interface ApiParams extends HttpParams {
  _page: number;
  _limit: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoviesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getList(page: number, limit: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://api-test.cnx-network.com/api/fuuze/content', 
      { params: { 
          page: page + '', 
          limit: limit + '', 
          category: 'movies',
          sort: 'order'
        }
      });
  }
}
```

don't understand how i can implement the page number interface ApiParams
I do not want to display a specific number of content but all the content

Comment: Please also share the movieService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzh2l1) your this.moviesList.length is 20 then why are you compare with paginate ? You are sending total count also from api then u can create total paginate from this count. In demo create one parameter with `totalPage` then in first call in ngOnInit

```
this.totalPage=parseInt((data.total/20).toString());
data.total%20>0 ? this.totalPage++ : this.totalPage;
```

then in your function use this as compare

```
nextMoviesList() {
    if(this.totalPage==this.currentPage){return;}  
    this.currentPage++  
    this.moviesService.getList(this.currentPage+1, 20).subscribe(data => {
        this.moviesList = data.content;
    });
}
```

If your service works with paginate then in your `nextMoviesList` function call service with new page index